# How does Matlab's simulannealbnd enforce bound constraints?

Tags: matlab, simulated-annealing

I'm using the [simulannealbnd](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/gads/simulannealbnd.html) Function of Matlab for finding the minimum of a function using simulated annealing. As arguments one can pass lower and upper bounds of the variables. In the documentation it is described how simulated annealing works but there is nothing about how the bound constraints are enforced.

Does somebody know (or can imagine) how this is done in this case?

Comment: The docs do state "Lower bounds, specified as a real vector or real array. If the number of elements in x0 is equal to that of lb, then lb specifies that

x(i) >= lb(i) for all i.

If numel(lb) < numel(x0), then lb specifies that

x(i) >= lb(i) for 1 <= i <= numel(lb).

In this case, solvers issue a warning." however. Otherwise I'm unsure whether anyone outside MathWorks can help you. Does `open simulannealbnd` work? Then you can at least read the code.

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, I can read the code but the code calls a lot of subfunctions in sequence and I did not find a solution.